# Как сделать что бы не появлялся горизантальный скролл?

Tags: html, css

Для скрытия меню задал `transform translateX(100%)`.

При открытие добавляется класс и меню встает на `translateX(0)`.

Все бы отлично но и за этого на мобильных и гаджетах с возможностью свайпа появляется скролл.

Если задать для `body` `overflow: hidden` не помогает.

Если задать и для `html` то убирается, но если для `body` и `html` задать `overflow-x:hidden` появляется доп. ненужные баги, т.е этот вариант не рассматриваю.

Какие есть еще варианты?

Comment: А можно узнать что за такие доп. ненужные баги у вас появляются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

попробуй

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет горизонтального скролла:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
    $sidebar = $('.js-sidebar');

  $sidebar.toggleClass('show');
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

main {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #eee;
}

sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  background: orangered;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}

sidebar.show {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

<sidebar class="js-sidebar">SideBar</sidebar>
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
</nav>
<main>
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
</main>
```

Если с правой стороны:

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var $this = $(this),
    $sidebar = $('.js-sidebar');

  $sidebar.toggleClass('show');
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  display: flex;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

main {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #eee;
}

sidebar {
  width: 200px;
  background: orangered;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

sidebar.show {
  transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>

<sidebar class="js-sidebar">SideBar</sidebar>
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
</nav>
<main>
  <h1>Main Content</h1>
</main>
```